# Question about roots of $x^n = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Theorem.
For every $n\in\Bbb N$ there exists exactly $n$ complex numbers whose $n$-th power is equal to $1$, in other words they are roots of $x^n=1$.

Proof.

Let's say $z=|z|(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)$ is root of $x^n=1$. Using de Moivre's formula we get
$$
|z|^n\cos(n\phi)=1
$$
$$|z|^n\sin(n\phi)=0.
$$

We get
$$
z=z_k=\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n}.
$$

Now this next part of proof of my lecture notes I can't understand.

Then,
$$
z_k=z_m\iff \exists s\in Z(\frac{2\pi k}{n}=\frac{2\pi m}{n}+2\pi s)\iff \exists s\in Z(k=m+ns).
$$
Then if me make make set
$$
C_n=\left\{z_k=\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi k}{n};k\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}\right\}.
$$

So from this follows that $C_n$ has $n$ numbers.

> Can you please explain me part of where introduces $s$ like how from $k=m+ns$ we know that there are $n$ roots?

Comment: Two angles are the same if they differ only by an integer number of full rotations. A full rotation is $2\pi$ radians. $2\pi s$, with $s\in\mathbb{Z}$ is any number of full rotations.

Comment: @plop I understand that,I don't understand from $k=m+ns$ we get $n$ roots?

Comment: Sum the fractions $\frac{2\pi m}{n}+2\pi s=\frac{2\pi (m+ns)}{n}$. If $k=m+ns$, then this fraction is equal to $\frac{2\pi k }{n}$. So, modifying $k$ by a multiple of $n$ doesn't change the angle. Therefore, the angle only cares about the remainder of $k$ after division by $n$. There are only $n$ remainders possible: $0,1,2,...,n-1$. So, only $n$ angles for the roots.

Comment: $k$ could have any values, but the angles that you obtain start to repeat. $k=0$ will give the same angle as $k=n$ and as $k=2n$, or $k=3n$. Likewise $k=1$ will give the same angle as $k=n+1$, or $k=2n+1$.

Comment: Thank you very much I understand now.

Comment: @plop you should make your comments an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $C_n$ uses the $n$ angles $0\le z_k \lt 2\pi$. Note that the statement above this is "if and only if".

There are $n$ of these angles (the integers $0$ to $n-1$ are used to index) and any pair differs by less than $2\pi$, so these are distinct.

Any other $z_k$ for integer $k$ differs from one of these angles by a multiple of $2\pi$ and therefore represents a root which has already been included.